# get promise value in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a helper function in my component. When I `console.log(helperFunction())` it, I get this in the console.

[image]

When I try to add the helper function to an input field for its value. I get this showing up.

[image]

How do I get the `[[PromiseValue]]` in my input?

```
  render() {
    console.log(getProjectName());
    return (
      <form ref={(input) => this.eventForm = input} onSubmit={(e) => this.createEvent(e)} className="slds-form">
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Assigned To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.assigned = input} type="text" className="slds-input"  disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Related To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.related = input} type="text" className="slds-input" defaultValue={getProjectName()} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Subject</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.subject = input} type="text" className="slds-input"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Location</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.location = input} type="text" className="slds-input" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event Start</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.start = input} type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} className="slds-input" value={ this.state.start }/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event End</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.end = input} type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} className="slds-input" value={ this.state.end } />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Contact</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.contact = input} type="text" className="slds-input" disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" className="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" className="slds-button slds-button--brand">Create</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Helper Function

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function getProjectName() {

  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

  // gets the record id from the current url
  function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");

    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
    }

    return(false);
  }

  // used to access the rest api on my system
  const REST_API_URL = restApiUrl;
  const API_TOKEN = {
    headers: { "Authorization" : "Bearer " + sessionId,
              "Content-Type" : "application/json"
             }
  }
  const OPPORTUNITY_QUERY = "SELECT+Id,Name+FROM+OPPORTUNITY+WHERE+Id="

  // get projectId
  const id = getQueryVariable('projectId');

  // make requst for record name
  var request = axios.get(`${REST_API_URL}query/?q=${OPPORTUNITY_QUERY}'${id}'`,
     API_TOKEN
   ).then(function (response){
      return resolve(response.data.records[0].Name);
   })
  })
}
```

Comment: You're printing out the promise object instead the resolved value, but unless you skip the images and post some code instead it will be hard to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @DanielB done, sorry

Comment: @DanielB how do I print the resolved value?

Comment: `getProjectName()` returns a promise. If that promise resolves a value, it should be possible to just run `getProjectName().then((value) => { console.log(value); });`, but it would be better if you included the code for the `getProjectName` function.

Comment: but how do I put that resolved value in my `input` in my jsx?

Comment: @DanielB it's been added

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When dealing with a value that the render method will be using and is also retrieved asynchronously you should be having that value exist in the state of the component and take advantage of the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to retrieve the value.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      projectName: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // fetch the project name, once it retrieves resolve the promsie and update the state. 
    this.getProjectName().then(result => this.setState({
      projectName: result
    }))
  }

  getProjectName() {
    // replace with whatever your api logic is.
    return api.call.something()
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <input type="text" defaultValue={projectName}>
    )
  }
 }
```

you don't want to call the function and resolve the promise in the render method because render method should be a pure function based on state and props. This is a base example but should give you an idea of what needs to change. Just need to set `projectName` as a state variable and make and resolve the promise in the `componentDidMount` on the first render it will equal an empty string, once it comes back it will update to whatever the api returns.

If you don't want to show the input until the api call resolves then you can just add additional checks to see if `this.state.projectName` equals anything and if so render the input.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is this part.

`<input ref={(input) => this.related = input} type="text" className="slds-input" defaultValue={getProjectName()} disabled/>`.

The function `getProjectName` returns a promise, not the resolved value of that promise.

You should render your UI with `render()` from `this.state` and `this.props`, and if you have data that has to be loaded asynchronously, you can assign the data to i.e. `this.props.relatedTo` using the `componentDidMount()` function, something in the line of

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;

    getProjectName()
        .then(val => {
            self.setState({relatedTo: val});
        });
}
```

Take a look at [the state and lifecycle documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I used to get a value from a promise was to use localstorage. I put the value in localstorage while in the promise function and accessed the value from the localstorage elsewhere.
Worked like a charm .

```
UserApi.current()
.then((result) => {
  console.log(" name is ",result.name);
  localStorage.setItem("name", result.name);
});
console.log("************ name **************",localStorage.getItem("name"));
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using localstorage as a method for retrieving data from a promise in React for two reasons:
1. React won't know when localstorage has been updated and therefore won't trigger an update.
2. Localstorage should be used to hold data across http requests where JavaScript state would be reset. Where this is not necessary, JavaScript (or React) state is a better place to hold this information.