# Unable to render promise response to html div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I have a rect component under whose componentDidMount method I am updating the state variable of component, and that state variable is used in render method to show on UI. but my div is always empty and on console I am seeing the error.Below are my component and js files content

**App.js**

```
componentDidMount () {
    ...
    this.someInternalMethod()
}

someInternalMethod() {
    someApiCall().then(result => {
      this.state.divContent.setContent(result)
    })
}
```

**apiHelper.js**

```
export function someApiCall() {

    // Build the api endpoint
    var url = "http://someurl";

    fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          return;
        }
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            //this log is printing data after error 
          console.log(data);
          return formattedHtmlData(data));
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log("Sorry data can't be loaded");
    });
}
```

**Formatter.js**

```
export function formattedHtmlData(data) {

    //do html formatting of data put inside div etc.
    and return
}
```

Not able to figure out what I am missing. Any help appreciated.

PS : Already referred this question on stackoverflow - [get promise value in react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308244/get-promise-value-in-react-component)

Comment: "and on console I am seeing the error" - What error did you get?

Comment: Could you include the error you got in the question? The way you call `someApiCall` looks a bit odd. It should be `someApiCall(marker, this.state.infowindow)`. You also need to return the `fetch` from `someApiCall`.

Comment: App.js:103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: @Tholle updated the question, `someApiCall` is imported from apiHelper.js

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne Great. You still need to return the `fetch` from `someApiCall`, or else there will be not promise for your to use `then` on in `someInternalMethod`.

Comment: @Tholle could you answer what you are suggesting not able to get it

Comment: Promise should be returned from someApiCall using new Promise or $q library only then you could use .then in react component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you return both your `fetch` and your `response.json()` calls, or the promise chain will be broken, and there will be no promise for you to use `then` on in `someInternalMethod`.

```
export function someApiCall() {
  // Build the api endpoint
  var url = "http://someurl";

  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        return;
      }
      return response.json().then(function(data) {
        //this log is printing data after error
        console.log(data);
        return formattedHtmlData(data);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Sorry data can't be loaded");
    });
}
```