# correct output of async await promise?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the firstore, and I get information from the first.

Here, I want to retrieve data from the firstore and print it out, but there is a problem with asynchronous mode.

The output is output after undefined.

I want to know how to print it correctly.

When data is received, the function receives data, and the method of receiving data after searching the firestore.

in react component

```
  index = (date) =>{

        let date_total = UserAction.getIndex(date)

       return date_total
    }

render(){
 const {user_list} = this.props;
        console.log(this.state)
        const date = "2020-02-24"
        console.log("data",date)
        let index = this.index(date) < this
        console.log("index", index)

return(...)
```

and useraction function

```
export function getIndex(data){
    let time_now = moment(data).utc().format()
    const user_history_start = moment(time_now).startOf("d").utc().format();
    const user_history_end = moment(time_now).endOf("d").utc().format();
    let db = loadFB().firestore();
    let query = db.collection('users').where('create_date','>=',user_history_start).where('create_date','<=',user_history_end);
    let number ;
    return query.get().then( docs=>{

        number = docs.size
        return number
    })



 }
```

i want output

```
data 2020-02-24
index 11 < (firestore given data)
```

but output

```
data 2020-02-24
index promise{<pending>} < (firestore given data)
```

Give me a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can't print a promised value in render, set the state and print it instead?

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    index: null
  }
}

getIndex = (date) => {
  // --------- update ----------
  UserAction.getIndex(date).then(date_total => this.setState({ index: date_total }))
}

componentDidMount() {
  const date = "2020-02-24"
  // --------- update ----------
  this.getIndex(date)
}

render() {
  console.log("index", this.state.index)
  // will first print null, 
  // then print the index when the promise is done (re-rendered due to state change)
}
```

You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308244/get-promise-value-in-react-component) as a reference.

Comment: I tried the two methods that I suggested, but the output I want is not available and the pending is output.

Comment: @이창훈 does it help?